# Some Facebook Pages Show Tabs On The Top Of Page, And Others On The Left. Why?

Tags: facebook

I am developing a Facebook page for my web design/development business, and I've noticed that the page I have created has the tabs aligned to the left hand side of the page underneath the page image. I then look at other pages such as Wetherspoons and Porsche and their tabs are aligned to the top of the page. Why is it like this? Is there a configuration I've missed that allows you to change the layout of the tabs?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Facebook is changing their profiles to the version with the tabs on the side. I believe that they are doing this to unify the pages and the profiles and make them more similar to one another. They are also letting people use facebook from the point of view of thier page. But its not a setting, you just caught facebook in the middle of their rollout.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. It's just I'll be doing work like this for clients and dont want them to say "well those tabs are at the top". Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Your page is using the new "Upgraded" Facebook layout. Wetherspoons and Porsche are using the old layout but will be automatically upgraded on March the 10th. There's nothing you can do about it if you prefer the old layout.